# Use of noun + からみると

Tags: grammar

I was looking at example sentences of the form  Xからみると... with the meaning of "from the point of view of X...".

It seems that most of the time the "point of view" part can be omitted, e.g. 先生からみると is "from the teacher's point of view.  However, with 私, the example was 私の立場からみると. The 'point of view' (立場) is explicitly included. I wondered if it was grammatical/natural to just say 私からみると. A google search for the phrase was less than convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about 私からみると, but it is just not so common to use it as *from my point of view*.

From [Shonagon](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/)

- われわれからみると，すごくおかしいと思います．
- 私からみると異風に見えますが

Removing 思う or 見える here makes them a little odd to me. (?われわれからみると、すごくおかしい. ?私からみると異風だ). Adding 立場 does not really change this, so whether or not 私(の立場)からみると is natural depends on many factors like register of the whole passage, or content of the following sentence.

Generally speaking, 私に言わせると is a more common way to put it (literally, *if you let me express my opinion*).